# Is there any way to know if render function was called because parent modification (props) or because internal state has changed?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React,

I would like to know if there is any way to know if render function was called because parent modification (props) or because internal state has changed?

Let say I have an `<input type"text" />`. I would like its value to change on keydown (onChange function) or each time props (from parent) has changed

Comment: are you not seeing the html you put into the render method?

Comment: Don't understand your comment

Comment: typically the render method has some html inside it's return(). if you have a div housing a p-tag that says "test", and you see "test" rendered to your browser, you'd know for sure it's being called

Comment: I updated my question, according to your answer it looks like It wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare your old and new props and state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  Object.entries(this.props).forEach(([key, val]) =>
    prevProps[key] !== val && console.log(`${key} prop was changed`)
  );
  Object.entries(this.state).forEach(([key, val]) =>
    prevState[key] !== val && console.log(`${key} state changed`)
  );
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `componentDidUpdate` and not `componentWillUpdate`?

Comment: `componentWillUpdate` is UNSAFE now https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillupdate but, if you want make your check before `render` method, you can use `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()``

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I gave+1), but it doesn't answer my question. Maybe I wasn't clear enough, so I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a console.log(this.props) or (props) whichever the case, inside render function, and it will log the props on console.